# Operator ! cannot be applied to int

Tags: java, operators, not-operator

In C++, `!1` means `false` which is equivalent to `0`. I apply the same rule in Java, but IDE told me `!` cannot be applied to int. Is there any way in Java to apply `!` to int instead of just writing `true` or `false`?

Comment: No. Java doesn't let you treat anything other than boolean or Boolean as a boolean.

Comment: ...and I am glad about that.

Comment: Why not just use `i != 0` instead of `!i`?

Comment: [Official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) `!`       Logical complement operator; inverts the value of a `boolean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in Java.
In java ! can operate only on boolean as negate operator, 1/0 are not considered as booleans in Java

Answer (score 1):

! only applies to Boolean values in Java, or the results of conditional statements. The closest thing you could do is `if (x == 1)` or `boolean y =  x == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, operators do not work on primitive data types, with the exception of, of-course, booleans. Using `!0` would simply result in an error. Even though 0s and 1s can be considered boolean values, they are not in Java. The negation operator is only for booleans. Something like `!0` would be:

```
boolean alwaysfalse = (0 != 0);
```

or

```
boolean alwaysTrue = (0 == 0);
```